# weak convergence of product of weakly and strongly convergent $L^{2}$ sequences in $L^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence, closed-graph

there is one question bothering me for quite a while now.

Let $a_{n},b_{n}\in L^{2}:a_{n}\stackrel{L^{2}}{\rightharpoonup} a\in L^{2} $ weakly $ b_{n}\stackrel{L^{2}}{\rightarrow} b \in L^{2}$ strongly and $a_{n}\cdot b_n\in L_{2}$ weakly and let all the sequences, also the product sequence, be bounded in $L^{2}$, that means w.l.o.g. $a_{n}\cdot b_n\stackrel{L^{2}}{\rightharpoonup}c\in L^{2}$ weakly

I'd like to prove that $a_{n}\cdot b_{n}\stackrel{L^{2}}{\rightharpoonup} a\cdot b$, that means $a\cdot b=c$.

---

My comments:

It would be enough to show that the nemytskij-operator of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\Omega\ni\left(u_{1},u_{2},x\right)\mapsto u_{1}\cdot u_{2}\in\mathbb{R}$ to be weakly closed

EDIT but this is wrong in general. It would STILL BE ENOUGH to prove that this nemytskij-operator is weakly$\times$strongly-closed. (the first function can be considered as the derivative of the first, so by sobolew embeding it converges strongly)

does anyone have an idea or a hint for literature?

Comment: how do you choose $a_{n}$ and $a_{b}$ such that $a_{n}$ converges weakly and $b_{n}$ converges strongly such that the product $a_{n}\cdot b_{n}$ is a rademacher sequence?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I read it as weak convergence for both.

Comment: i will edit and make this more clear... i think if i'd have read the question i might have reacted the same way :-)

Comment: You might want to edit the title, also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact $a_nb_n\in L^1(\Omega)$ not $L^2(\Omega)$, and 
$$
\int_\Omega a_nb_n\,dx \to \int_\Omega ab\,dx.
$$ 
Indeed,
$$
a_nb_n-ab=a_n(b_n-b)+(a_n-a)b
$$
Then
$$
\Big|\int_\Omega a_n(b_n-b)\,dx\,\Big|\le 
\|a_n\|_{L^2}\|b_n-b\|_{L^2}\le M\|b_n-b\|_{L^2}\to 0,
$$
and
$$
\int_\Omega (a_n-a)b \to 0, 
$$

### as $a_n-a\rightharpoonup 0$.

EDIT by OP:
this argumentation gives $a_{n}\cdot b_{n}\stackrel{L^{1}}{\rightarrow}a\cdot b$.

together with

$a_{n}\cdot b_{n}\stackrel{L^{2}}{\rightarrow}c \Rightarrow a_{n}\cdot b_{n}\stackrel{L^{1}}{\rightarrow}c$

it follows that $a\cdot b = c$

Comment: note that i assumed $b_{n}\rightarrow b$

Comment: yes, this might help, can you check my arguments please?:

I have $a_{n}\cdot b_{n}\stackrel{L^{1}}{\rightharpoonup}a\cdot b$. I also have $a_{n}\cdot b_{n}\stackrel{L^{2}}{\rightharpoonup}c$ . This also implies $a_{n}\cdot b_{n}\stackrel{L^{1}}{\rightharpoonup}a\cdot b$ so I finally get$\Rightarrow a\cdot b=c$.

Comment: There is a problem that can not be taken care of: $a_n\cdot b_n\not\in L^2$ in general.

Comment: this is not a problem, it's assured for my special sequence because i take a minimizing sequence of a certain functional... :-)

Comment: Your argument is correct if you have this information.

Comment: i will accept the answer. anyway, can you edit it and include the stuff i wrote in my last comment? (then it actually answers the question exactly and other people dont have to read the comments)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: wait, what you have shown is even $a_{n}\cdot b_{b}\stackrel{L^{1}}{\rightarrow}a\cdot b$ strongly this is great... because maybe i'll have to choose an almost everywhere convergent subsequence :-)

Answer (score -1):

There is a disproof of this statement in general. Take $ L^2([-1,1],\mathbb{C})$, and $a_n(x)= \exp(2\pi i n x)$ and $b_n (x) = \exp(-2\pi i n x)$. In this case, both $a_n \rightharpoonup a = 0$ and $b_n\rightharpoonup b=0$, but $a_n (x)\cdot b_n(x) =1$ for all $x$. Clearly $c_n=c =1$. Then 
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{-1}^1 a_n(x)\cdot b_n(x)\,dx=2$$
but 
$$\int_{-1}^1 a(x)\cdot b(x)\,dx =0$$