# Product between weakly convergent sequence and strongly convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Can someone help me,  I am stuck in this easy problem

Let $I=(0,1)$, $1<p<\infty$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. If $f_n$ converges weakly to $f \in L^p(I)$ and $g_n$ converges (strongly) to $g \in L^q(I)$, then
$$f_ng_n \rightharpoonup fg \text{ (converges weakly in) } L^1(I)$$

Also I am very curious with the statement "$g_n$ converges strongly to $g$" can be change with "$g_n \rightharpoonup g$"

Comment: Surely you have tried something. How would you start? Please share.

Comment: I tried to prove "if $u\in L^{p}(I)$ and $v \in L^{\infty}(I)$ then $u v \in L^{p}(I)$" because I think this will be helpful, but I dont know :(

Comment: Isn't $|uv|^p \le |u|^p\|v\|_\infty^p$ a.e.? And when I asked where you would start, I mean at least state what you're trying to prove clearly and precisely.

Comment: Just generalize this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686494/weak-convergence-of-product-of-weakly-and-strongly-convergent-l2-sequences?rq=1